# How can I save the user model "id" Automatic

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

to verify the login password

```
class Summaries(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
```

extended model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Summaries, related_name = "student", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Фамилия")
```

create data within a personal data

```
class additional(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name = "marks", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

additional data is stored

```
def create_resume(request):
    context = {}
    additionalFormset = modelformset_factory(additional, form=additionalForm)  
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    formset = additionalFormset(request.POST or None, queryset= additional.objects.none(), prefix='additional')
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    student = form.save(commit=False)
                    student.save()
                    form.save_m2m()

                    for guar in formset:
                        data = guar.save(commit=False)
                        data.student = student
                        data.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                print("Error Encountered")

            return redirect('summary_vacancy:meine_biografiess')


    context['formset'] = formset
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'summary_vacancy/create_resume.html', context)
```

I saved an additional model
I have to add the "id" myself when I create new data

How can I save the User model "id"  transaction.atomic():

i don't understand for 3 modules